# Фон при ресайзе портится

Tags: php

Фон при ресайзе png становится черным, а не прозрачным.

```
function resize($photo_src, $width, $name){  
 $parametr = getimagesize($photo_src);  
 list($width_orig, $height_orig) = getimagesize($photo_src);  
  $ratio_orig = $width_orig/$height_orig;  
 $new_width = $width;  
  $new_height = $width / $ratio_orig;  

$newpic = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
imagesavealpha( $newpic, true ); 

 switch ( $parametr[2] ) {  
  case 1: $image = imagecreatefromgif($photo_src); 
   break;  
   case 2: $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($photo_src);   
   break;  
  case 3: $image = imagecreatefrompng($photo_src);  
   break;  
 }

imagecopyresampled($newpic, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width_orig, $height_orig);  
imagejpeg($newpic, $name, 100);
return true; 
}
```

Comment: У JPEG нет альфа-канала. Т.е. нельзя сделать прозрачность. Я давно не работал с изображениями в PHP, попробуйте вместо `imagejpeg` сохранить `imagepng`

Answer (score 1):

если вы работаете с библиотекой GD то там все очень плохо с обработкой альфа канала, попробуйте юзать imageK - там все намного проще и обработка картинок при ресайзе намного легче...вся проблема в прозрачности...